# Nextjs docs claim state is not lost between navigation? (Client side cache)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In the Nextjs App router [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#router-cache) about Client side cache it says:

- No full-page reload between navigations and **React state and browser state is preserved**.

I can't reproduce it. See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tutnca?description=The%20React%20framework%20for%20production&file=app%2Flayout.tsx&title=Next.js%20Starter).

- Click "First Link" button, increase counter
- Click "Second Link" button
- Click "Back", to go back where the "First Link" took you
- See the counter state is 0 again

Why was the counter reset? According to above quote wasn't the counter supposed to retain value?

Comment: I doubt the docs are incorrect.  If you did not get an answer here, try creating an issue in the NextJs Github repo - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues

Comment: @kiranvj I opened discussion first on their gh (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/58540), if I don't get answer there I'll open issue. Sometimes they ignore the issues, that's why I tried first here. It is good they at least allow you to open documentation related issues, some repos don't even allow that. In general I've noticed some issues with their docs.

Comment: Why are you expection use client component to be cached? It works as it worked before, component unmounts and loses state. Caching is added in React Server components

Comment: @VladVladov Have a look at the quote ("No full-page reload between navigations and React state and browser state is preserved.") I cited from the doc about client side cache.

Comment: also from this docs: `Next.js has an in-memory client-side cache that stores the React Server Component Payload` - so it ony works in RSC

Comment: @VladVladov Notice how the quote I cited mentions "react state", server components don't have react state as you may know.

Comment: @VladVladov There is also another quote in the docs elsewhere which makes this situation again confusing: "By default, the browser performs a hard navigation between pages. This means the browser reloads the page and resets React state such as useState hooks in your app and browser state such as the user's scroll position or focused element. However, in Next.js, the App Router uses soft navigation. This means React only renders the segments that have changed while preserving React and browser state, and there is no full page reload." (check gh discussion above for link)

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Can you try adding state in a `Layout` component and check if the child component states are retained on page navigation

Comment: @kiranvj AFAIK if you have state in layout it preserves state in layout when navigating between children - but it does not preserve state in children in that case.

Comment: @kiranvj Here is the issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/58699, but no answer yet. Last time they ignored another issue I opened about docs.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava The docs are confusing for sure for both newbies and experts.

Comment: @kiranvj Like I mentioned this is not the first instance of problem I found in the docs. I don't know what else I can do. How can I bring their attention to these issues? As one can see, this issue seems to be ignored so far too (similar to one of my other older doc issues).